# How to search numbers inside brackets in GVIM

Tags: regex, vim

In Gvim, how do I search "numbers inside square brackets".

I tried the following search `/[*]` but it resulted in highlighting all pattern in between brackets including alphabetic characters.

I want to search only the numbers in between square brackets, is there any wild card ? Can someone help me out ?

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but I don't see another question about this issue specifically.

Comment: Could it be possible to reword this into proper english? Being a servant of Her Majesty and all that, one expects higher standards from such as yourself. b/w?

Answer (score 4):

`vim` (and `gvim`) search via regular expressions.  In this case, you can do `/\[[0-9]\+\]` (or the shorthand `/\[\d\+\]` as Istvan mentioned).

See also:

- `:help search`
- [Search and Replace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)
- [Vim tips: The basics of search and replace](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/8255-vim-tips-the-basics-of-search-and-replace)

Comment: Hi guys thanks for ur solution,need one more solution on this i wnat to replace with backslash ,like this if i have [0] or [9] i want to replace it with \[0\] or \[9\] ,,so how to do this

Comment: Guys any solution on this i wnat to replace with backslash ,like this if i have [0] or any number [9] i want to replace it with \[0\] or \[9\]

Comment: The linked tutorials should help you out.  What are you finding confusing?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`/\[\d*\]`

This will only work if you don't have letters, only numbers between the brackets.